# How to find a missing number from a list in Dart

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart, numbers

How to find a missing number from a list in Dart language

```dart
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

Comment: What is considered to be "missing"? Please provide more detail in your question and show an attempt.

Comment: number 7 is a missing

Comment: That really doesn't help. I see that the number 7 is missing, but it's not possible to generate code that considers *all* cases without understanding every possible input. If you just wanted to find if 7 for only this particular array every time, I could tell you that now and say always return false.

Comment: But what about the big lists that contain thousands of numbers

Comment: I don't know, I'm asking you. What's the pattern? What are the conditions? What are the possible inputs?

Comment: Is it only ever one missing number?

Comment: If so it is just math, see answer on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18424/find-missing-number-from-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int num in a){
  if(a.contains(num+1) == false && a.last != num){
    return num+1
  }
   return null; // No missing value
}
```

Assuming you want to find 7 in the example you could do something like this. It checks if the next value is provided. It is also necessary to check for the last element because `lastElement+1` will always not be included in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the list is sorted you can use:

```
Iterable<int> findMissingInts(List<int> ints) sync* {
  for (var i = 0; i < ints.length - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = ints[i] + 1; j < ints[i + 1]; j++) {
      yield j;
    }
  } 
}

main() {
  print(findMissingInts([1,2,4,5,8])); //(3, 6, 7)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sum formula n*(n+1)/2 its easy to figure out..

```
import "dart:math";

main(){
  var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10];
      
  int n = a.reduce(max);
  
  var sum = n*(n+1)/2;
  
  var sumOfArray = a.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
  
  print(sum-sumOfArray);
}
```